# ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' ' python

Tags: python

i have this in file

```
1
1
GALAXY S10
1000
MOVIL
1
1
2
2
IPHONE
1200
MOVIL
2
2
3
3
MAC
1400
ORDENADOR
2
3
```

my code:

```
listProducto1 = [1,"GALAXY S10", 1000, "MOVIL",1,1]
listProducto2 = [2,"IPHONE", 1200, "MOVIL",2,2]
listProducto3 = [3,"MAC", 1400, "ORDENADOR",2,3]

diccProductos = {1:listProducto1,2:listProducto2,3:listProducto3}
diccAuxiliar ={}

f=open(fichero,"w")
for clave in diccProductos.keys():
    f.write(str(clave)+"\n")
    for valor in diccProductos.keys():
        f.write(str(diccProductos[clave][valor-1])+"\n")
f.close()

f=open(fichero,"r")
lineas=f.read().split("\n")
contador=0

for linea in lineas:
    if (contador==0):
        varAux=str(linea)
        #varAux=linea
        #varKey = int(float(varAux))
        #varKey = int(varAux)
        print(contador,varAux)
        diccAuxiliar[varAux]=[]
    else:
        varValor=linea
        print("contador: ",contador," |valor :",varValor)
        diccAuxiliar[varAux].append(varValor)
    contador+=1

    if (contador==7):
        contador=0

print(diccAuxiliar["1"][3])
```

to find the key I have to use string and I want to use an integer, when I do var = int (line) it is my mistake, I tried to use float

My idea is to pass a dictionary that contains a list to a file and then take the file and make it visceverous to continue working with that dictionary without using pickle, csv, json, etc.

Comment: "to find the key I have to use string and I want to use an integer"... Why don't you just use a list of lists instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code can be much cleaner if you use just a list of lists. With this approach your first product will start at `0` instead of `1` and you are going every product will have `6` lines on the output file, instead of `7`, as you have in the code you posted.

Here is a solution that implements the concept I described using Python 3.6+ (because of `f-strings`):

```py
from pathlib import Path

products = [
    [1, "GALAXY S10", 1000, "MOVIL", 1, 1],
    [2, "IPHONE", 1200, "MOVIL", 2, 2],
    [3, "MAC", 1400, "ORDENADOR", 2, 3]
]

filename = Path('outputfile.txt')
lines_per_product = len(products[0])

with filename.open('w') as f:
    for product in products:
        for value in product:
            f.write(f'{value}\n')

products_aux = []

with filename.open() as f:
    lines = [_.strip() for _ in f.readlines()]
    for i in range(0, len(lines), lines_per_product):
        products_aux.append([
            int(_) if _.isdigit() else _
            for _ in lines[i:i + lines_per_product]
        ])

print(products_aux[0][3])
```

Comment: thank you very much, it is another way to raise the products that for lack of experience I had not planned for files

Comment: @Jesus1991, no worries. I'm glad it worked for you.